# binding to observable collection silverlight 4, grid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Can I bind a simple 'grid' to an observable collection? So i have a grid with just one column and several rows. The rows get populated at runtime with some hyperlinks which can get deleted/added etc. I don't want to write functions to add/remove them from the grid everytime and would prefer to use an observable collection and let the grid update itself. Can a simple grid do that ? i tried but it didn't even compile.

Thanks

[EDIT] Solved. The marked answer is correct [/EDIT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers cover various bases but your specific requirement is filled by the `ItemsControl`.  You would probably want to contain it in `ScrollViewer` just in case where you have more links than can be seen at one time.  You would have markup something like this:-

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyObsCollectionOfUrlInfo">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <HyperLinkButton NavigateUri={Binding Uri} Content={Binding Title} />
          </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Your observable collection would contain a list of objects of a type like:-

```
 public class UrlInfo
 {
      public Uri Uri {get; set; }
      public string Title {get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: You Sir, have hit the nail on its head. I looked at the link above and it seemed a bit too hackish too me. So I did everything using a datagrid then saw your solution, seemed really simple to not even try. Try I did and it worked like a charm. Simple is beautiful ! Thank you

Comment: May be I was a bit hasty there. It's not really working too well and I'm not sure why. Please see the [EDIT][/EDIT] section in my post above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not support this. You have two options, either use a `DataGrid` or use the following code that allows you to use a `Grid` within an `ItemsControl` which will achieve what you are after.

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/11/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol/

Answer (score 0):

@ColinE is correct, you can't bind to a `Grid`, but you **can** bind an `ObservableCollection` to a `DataGrid` or an `ItemsControl`.